The Mathematics of Predicting the Future
I'm predicting the future of a deck of cards. Specifically, I have a deck of $2n$ cards: $n$ are red, and $n$ are black. The deck is shuffled uniformly randomly.
I'm dealing out the cards one by one, and trying to predict what color each card will be, before I see it.
I don't have any special powers, so I guess at the cards as follows: I count how many cards of each color have been dealt, and I pick the color I've seen less often so far.
With this strategy, and $n=100$, I guess $108.37$ cards correctly, on average. The first 100 correct cards are nothing to get excited about: I could do that with my eyes closed. The next 8.37 correct cards are more exciting: That's my bonus for using a good strategy. Let's call the number of correct predictions, above $n$, my "bonus cards".
For larger and larger $n$, the number of bonus cards grows roughly like $\sqrt{n}$. For instance, for $n=10^4,$ the average number of bonus cards is $88.12$.
Question: As $n \to \infty$, what is the limiting value of the average number of bonus cards, divided by $\sqrt{n}$? How do you know?

The limiting ratio is

 $$  \frac {\sqrt\pi} 2 \approx 0.886$$

Reasoning:
First observe that every time the numbers of black and red cards seen so far

 are equal

offers a fifty-fifty chance to earn a bonus card simply by

 guessing the next card right.

Indeed,

 between consecutive ties the majority---once it is picked by the first card---does not change. Also, the numbers of black and red cards dealt between ties are equal. And because the majority does not change our policy will guess the same colour all the time and hence put us exactly at chance level. Except for the very first card which gives us a 50% chance of doing better.

We therefore need to count the expected number of times a tie will be seen.
The probability to be tied after $2k$ cards is

 $$ p_k := \frac  {\begin{pmatrix}2k \\ k\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2(N-k) \\ N-k \end{pmatrix}} {\begin{pmatrix}2N \\ N\end{pmatrix}}$$

Using the asymptotic expression

 $$\begin{pmatrix}2n \\ n\end{pmatrix}\simeq \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

for the binomial coefficient we get for the expected number of ties $T_N$ to be

 $$T_N = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \sqrt{\frac N {\pi k(N-k)}} = \sqrt{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi (k/N)(1-k/N)}}$$

Note that strictly speaking we should also count one of the endpoints, and also that the approximation is not good for small $k$. As we are, however, only interested in asymptotics this matters not.
Take the limit to get

 $$T_N / \sqrt{N} \to \frac 1 {\sqrt {\pi}} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{h(1-h)}}dh = \sqrt {\pi}$$

and half that for the expected number of bonus cards divided by $\sqrt{N}$.

This is a correct final answer, but it doesn't really answer why the expected number of bonus cards equals the expected number of correctly-guessed ties.

@isaacg I'm surprised that's the worst omission in your opinion ;-)   I've added an explanation.

Thanks for the update. Accepted!

Can you elaborate on how the sum is set up? I assume you did a Riemann sum

@BenjaminWang Yes, you basically change variables k -> k/N =: h.

The reasoning seems wrong on the following point. Between ties one gets 2 bonus cards on a successful first guess (and 0 on an initial wrong guess) since the last card before tie is always guessed correctly (and all but first and last balance out). Thus expected ties equals expected bonus cards.

@Retudin 2 out of 2 is only 1 above chance level, so this is correct.

Two out of two is indeed 1. But you end 'with bonus cards is half of ties' i.e 1/2 above chance level.. I am still missing a factor 2 somewhere when trying to follow the reasoning.

@Retudin 50% of the time you get the first wrong and end up at chance level, 50% of the time you get the first right and end up 1 above chance level. -> On average 1/2 above chance level.

OK not entirely sure why I was detracting wrong guesses, on a miss its indeed not -1,+1 good guess, but 0,+1 good guess for a difference of 1 with guessing right. Sorry for being confused, and thx for the replies.

I considered this problem a long ago and it caused interesting calculations, see here.
The average number of bonus cards should be

 $$n\int_0^1 x^n(2-x)^{n-1} dx=$$


 $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} n^{1/2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{16} n^{-1/2} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{256} n^{-3/2} - \frac{5 \sqrt{\pi}}{2048} n^{-5/2} + \cdots.$$

